# Which technique should I use for the given scenario?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I've a list of numbers(say A) , I want to find out how closely related another list of numbers(say B) is to A. By close relation, I mean  B should follow the same trend as  A , I want to show the closeness in terms of a number between 0 to 100 , where 100 would be exact match. Pls note that A and B are multivariate i.e. they are list of list of numbers. I was thinking curve-fitting (multivariate linear regression) should be enough but I don't know how to represent the result between 0 to 100. It would be really helpful if you could suggest a pre-built tensorflow model which I could import in colab.

Comment: This sounds like $R^2$ in linear regression (times $100$). Is there something about this that does not work for your purposes? "List" of numbers seems inconsistent with being multivariate, so I think a regression of $B$ on $A$ should work for you.

Comment: I don't understand why you want you want to build a TF model about this? This calls for a distance or similarity measure, which would give you a numerical value representing how close the two series are. If the series are ordered (i.e. the pair A[i] and B[i] represent values for the same 'thing') then you have plenty of choices: cosine, jaccard, minmax, etc. The choice should depend on what the values represent imho.